# Reference to object C++

Tags: c++11

I got a code like this

```
void ContactModel::archive(ArchiveStream &stream) {
stream & kn;
stream & ks;
stream & fric;
.
.
.
}
```

As I understand, stream is an object of ArchiveStream class. But if it is the case, how they use stream to define a bunch of new parameters kn, ks, fric?

I think I misunderstood it. So hope you could explain this code. I am really appreciate

Comment: Looks like they overloaded `operator&` on that class. (i.e. these are not variable declarations, they're plain expressions.)

Comment: @Mat Please turn your comment into an answer so that Nhu Nguyen can accept it.